# How do I populate a DatagridViewComboboxColumn

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am not sure how to populate a DatagridviewComboboxcolumn. There are several properties in the DataGridViewComboboxcolumn, and i am not sure which to use:

- DataSource
- Items
- DisplayMember
- ValueMember

I am confused there are that many properties. This is what I tried:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
cb.Items.Add("TEST");

//OR
 cb.DataSource = new List<String>() { "T", "E", "S", "T" };
```

Comment: What happens? You get an Exception?

Comment: No exception. The combobox is just blank and I can't select a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast it to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, not `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` :) For example:

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Items.Add("Something");
```

Comment: True point, but it still isn't working. Which means there is probably something missing..

Comment: I've tried it before posting and it worked for me. This works as well: `DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]; cb.Items.Add("TEST");`. Can you provide us the whole code of a method, where you're trying to do that?